# Discord.py clone my voice to other channels

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

Is there anyway I can create a bot using discord.py that joins my voice channel and share what I'm saying or whatever is playing to other voice channels in my server and other servers as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, larger bots like "Groovy" or "Rythm" allow use in multiple channels as they can be run on a completely different shard for each server, meaning it can be used and commands run to function in each and every server.

It seems in your case, it would not be able to do this, as it would be able to join multiple channels but can only have usage in one channel at a time.

I have found only Discord.js has a feature like this, but similar, it records user voice and saves it as an MP3 file.
The Discord. js voice system allows your bot to join voice channels and play audio. The main part is, Discord does not officially support Discord bots receiving audio [see here](http://Receiving%20Audio%20%7C%20Discord.js%20Guide), so there may be some breakages.

Obviously, you aren't using JS so this would not be possible, or at least very difficult to make. But hope this helps in some way.